# I'm trying to get data to datatables

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am trying to use ajax but ajax doesn't work. So I referred to: 
https://datatables.net/manual/ajax.

An object of data and still got nothing.

This is my Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
                ajax: 'notUsed.ad',
                columns: [
                {"data":'memNum'},
                {"data":'memId'},
                {"data":'memName'},
                {"data":'memGender'},
                {"data":'memPhone'},
                {"data":'nationCode'},
                {"data":'memPoint'},
                {"data":'memType'},
                {"data":'memStatus'},
                {"data":'enrollDate'},
                {"data":'noShow'}
                ]
            });
});
```

and HTML markup:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>num</th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>gender</th>
            <th>phone</th>
            <th>nation</th>
            <th>point</th>
            <th>type</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>enroll_date</th>
            <th>noshow</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

and servlet

```
public class TableMemSearch extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public TableMemSearch() {
        super();
    }

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ArrayList<Member> list = new AdminService().searchMember();

        JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();

        for (Member m : list) {
            JSONObject jsonMember = new JSONObject();
            jsonMember.put("memNum", String.valueOf(m.getMemNum()));
            jsonMember.put("memId", String.valueOf(m.getMemNum()));
            jsonMember.put("memName", String.valueOf(m.getMemName()));
            jsonMember.put("memGender", String.valueOf(m.getMemGender()));
            jsonMember.put("memPhone", String.valueOf(m.getMemPhone()));
            jsonMember.put("nationCode", String.valueOf(m.getNationCode()));
            jsonMember.put("memPoint", String.valueOf(m.getMemPoint()));
            jsonMember.put("memType", String.valueOf(m.getMemType()));
            jsonMember.put("memStatus", String.valueOf(m.getMemStatus()));
            jsonMember.put("enrollDate",String.valueOf(m.getEnrollDate()) );
            jsonMember.put("noShow",String.valueOf( m.getNoShow()));
            jArr.add(jsonMember);
        }
        jobj.put("data", jArr);

        response.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        response.getWriter().print(jobj);
```

it returns nothing.

No error, no result.

I don't know what to do. This is a screenshot of result and no error in eclipse:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdPJo.png)

Please help.8ㅅ8...

Comment: Can you provide the raw json retrieved from ajax request?

Comment: check network and console for any error . and is the ajax request being sent

Comment: raw providing jsonArray already tried :p
no error on console and alert